# AM, GM and HM relationship

Tags: geometry, self-learning

Question: Prove that $DO$, $DB$ and $DE$ are **AM**, **GM** and **HM** of $a$ and $b$ in the given figure.

It is given that $OA$ us the radius of this semi-circle.

[image]

I have proved $DO$ as **AM** of $a$ and $b$ simply by using the fact $DO$ is the radius of this semi-circle and will be equal to the half of the diameter $(a + b)$

And $DB$ can be proved as **GM** by first finding out $BO$ and the applying Pythagoras theorem in the triangle $DBO$.

But I'm stuck at proving $DE$ as **HM** of $a$ and $b$. I have tried it by first proving the triangles $DBO$ and $DEB$ similar and then using corresponding sides and area theorem but unable to conclude **HM**.

Kindly help.

Comment: BED is  similar to OBD so DE/DB=DB/DO.

Comment: @user254665 did it. I was trying it using area and sides of similar and was getting stuck evertime.

Comment: This kind of graphical representation is rather classical. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean where, in addition, the quadratic mean is represented.

Comment: The answer by Roman83 appeared at about the same time as my comment. I like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$R=AO=BO=OD=\frac{a+b}{2}$$
$$\angle ADC=90^{\circ} \Rightarrow DB^2=AB \cdot BC  \Rightarrow DB=\sqrt{ab}$$

$\triangle ODB \sim \triangle BDE \Rightarrow \frac{DB}{DO}=\frac{DE}{DB}$
$$DB^2=DE \cdot DO \Rightarrow DE=\frac{DB^2}{DO}=\frac {ab}{\frac{a+b}{2}}=\frac{2ab}{a+b}$$